# How to properly resolve "AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have an issue in Django.

- In `views.py` I need to import a form from `forms.py`
- This view is a class-based view, which means the form is in the module context because of:

  ```
  class SomeClassBasedView(FormView):
      form_class = MyModelForm
  ```
- Except then in `forms.py` I need to import a model from `models.py`

This means (I assume) that `models.py` is loaded before the App is properly loaded, causing:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

How can I cleanly construct a Class-based view with a `ModelForm`?

Comment: The form setup you describe is very common and would not normally cause this error. There must be something else causing it. Is that the full stack trace?

Comment: No, I was prematurely loading `urls.py`.